# How to synchronize JavaScript timer and animated progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code snippet (basically based on a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31111035/17019900)) that generates a timer and an associated progress bar. It works fine if one clicks `Start` button and just waits until the end (i.e., The progress bar animated to zero when the timer is counted down to `00:00`).

**What is problematic in this code snippet is that, when one clicks the `Pause` button and then the `Resume` button in between, the timer and the progress bar get *unsynchronized* when the time is set to `00:00`.**

How to resolve this issue?

```js
var timer = null;
var timePassed;
var TIME_LIMIT;
var timeLeft;


function startTimerAndProgressbar() {
    timePassed = 0;
    TIME_LIMIT = 10;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
    
    startTimer();
    initializeProgressBar()
    startProgressBar()
}

function pauseTimerAndProgressbar() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    pauseProgressBar();
    id("pause-btn").disabled = true;
    id("resume-btn").disabled = false;
}

function resumeTimerAndProgressbar() {
    startTimer();
    resumeProgressBar();
    id("pause-btn").disabled = false;
    id("resume-btn").disabled = true;
}


/* HELPER FUNCTION */
function id(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}


/* PROGRESS BAR */
function initializeProgressBar() {
    resetProgressBar();
    id("progress-bar").style.visibility = "visible";
    id("progress-bar-inner").style.animationDuration = TIME_LIMIT + "s";
    id("progress-bar-inner").style.animationPlayState = "paused";
}

function startProgressBar() {
    id("progress-bar-inner").style.animationPlayState = 'running';
}

function pauseProgressBar() {
    id("progress-bar-inner").style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
}

function resumeProgressBar() {
    id("progress-bar-inner").style.animationPlayState = 'running';
}

function initializeProgressBar() {
    resetProgressBar();
    id("progress-bar").style.visibility = "visible";
    id("progress-bar-inner").style.animationDuration = TIME_LIMIT + "s";
    id("progress-bar-inner").style.animationPlayState = "paused";
}

function resetProgressBar() {
    var element = id('progress-bar-inner');
    element.style.animation = 'none';
    element.offsetHeight; /* trigger a DOM reflow */
    element.style.animation = null;
}


/* TIMER */
function startTimer() {
    id("timer").textContent = formatTime(timeLeft);
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        timePassed = timePassed += 1;
        timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
        id("timer").textContent = formatTime(timeLeft);
        if (timeLeft == 0) { clearTimeout(timer); }
    }, 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
    var m = Math.floor(time / 60);
    var s = time % 60;
    m = (m < 10) ? ("0" + m) : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? ("0" + s) : s;
    return `${m}:${s}`;
}
```

```css
#timer {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#progress-bar {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 25px auto;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#progress-bar-inner {
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    animation: progressbar-countdown;
    animation-duration: 0s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes progressbar-countdown {
    0% {
        width: 100%;
        background: #ffc300;
    }
    100% {
        width: 0%;
        background: red;
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="timer"></p>
<div id="progress-bar">
    <div id="progress-bar-inner"></div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="startTimerAndProgressbar()" id="start-btn">Start</button>
<button onclick="pauseTimerAndProgressbar()" id="pause-btn">Pause</button>
<button onclick="resumeTimerAndProgressbar()" id="resume-btn" disabled>Resume</button>
```

Comment: Use `clearTimeout` with `setTimeout` and `clearInterval` with `setInterval`. `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are not particularly accurate. Tie your countdown to your animation and only start/stop/reset the animation. Make use of [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and [`Animation.currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/currentTime) to do this.